# How To Cite a Hyperlink in E-Book

Tags: citations, footnotes, memoir

I am editing an e-book memoir, and I am wondering how to properly use a hyperlink reference citation. There is only one such reference in the entire manuscript. After I put the superscript number 1 at the end of the sentence, my question is:

Should I make a footnote at the bottom of the page it is mentioned, or do I need to use a reference list at the end of the document?

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are the input and output formats?

Answer (score 2):

The SUBJECT of this question focuses on proper hyperlink citation. However, the narrative focuses on the correct usage of footnote/endnote. So, my answer will focus on the footnote/endnote usage.

The answer you seek might depend on your preference of style guide unless the document's publisher requires otherwise.

For instance, according to MLA Style, footnotes appear at the bottom of the same page referencing the footnote whereas endnotes appear at the end of the document on a separate page entitled "Endnotes or Notes."

Source: [A Resource Guide for Students, Chapter 7.](http://www.aresearchguide.com/7footnot.html)

Comment: What counts as "the bottom of the page" in an e-book?  (I assume the OP means something like epub or mobi, not a paginated format like PDF.)